# Where are my BTRFS subvolumes?

Tags: 18.04, server, system-installation, filesystem, btrfs

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 server on a VPS using the Ubuntu installer (from a mounted ISO image). I selected BTRFS as my filesystem type during the manual partitioning phase of installation.

Now that the installation has completed, I do not see `@` or `@home` like I normally would on the non-server install. I don't care about a `@home` subvolume here, but I do not want the top level volume mounted at `/`.

lsblk:

```
vda    252:0    0   25G  0 disk
|-vda1 252:1    0    1M  0 part
|-vda2 252:2    0   20G  0 part /
`-vda3 252:3    0    5G  0 part [SWAP]
```

The produces no results:

```
btrfs su li /
```

I tried this next:

```
btrfs filesystem show | awk '/ path /{print $NF}'
/dev/vda2
```

and:

```
# findmnt
TARGET    SOURCE     FSTYPE     OPTIONS
/         /dev/vda2  btrfs      rw,relatime,space_cache,subvolid=5,subvol=/
```

**How can I create BTRFS subvolumes during installation of 18.04 server?**

I would like to create `@` (for `/`) and `@varlog` (for `/var/log`) and maybe others.

I would like to use Snapper for hourly snapshots. Is there a recommended way to set up Ubuntu server with BTRFS and Snapper?

Comment: Why would you need it during installation? You can create subvolumes now as you wish.

Comment: The installer puts the root file system in the top level BTRFS volume. That's bad practice IMO. It's not the way I want to set up my server's file system. The root fs should be in a subvolume. That can't be fixed now. I have to reinstall and do it the right way. Ubuntu doesn't seem to understand BTRFS, or I don't understand Ubuntu's way of working with BTRFS...

Comment: It is not a "bad practice" and it can be easily fixed now. You can create a subvolume now and place `/` there with no problems. Only grub and fstab should be updated. You can snap your top subvol to `@`. It' the easiest way.

Comment: @Pilot6 - thank you. I look forward to knowing how to do it.

Comment: Thank you. The VPS does use grub. This should work. I will try now and accept your answer when I finish. Doesn't look hard. Thank you.

Comment: Beware I changed p.3 you don't need to mount `/boot` it can spoil things. This is when /boot is separate. If you mount it, the grub.cfg will ne in a wrong place.

Comment: I am not quite sure if `/boot` is needed in all cases. The `/boot/efi` can play a part. If it worked with `/boot`, I'll revert the change.

Comment: @Pilot6 I am checking further to be sure everything is OK. I'll respond after I check carefully.

Comment: It should be OK if it boots to the subvolume. There is nothing to worry about. Just be careful when you delete the top subvolume data not to `rm` the `/@`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can move your `/` to a subvolume this way:

1. Create a shapshot of your filesystem.

   ```
    btrfs sub snap / /@
   ```
2. Mount the new subvolume to `/mnt`.

   ```
    mount -o subvol=@ /dev/vda2 /mnt
   ```
3. Chroot to the subvolume and update grub.

   ```
    cd /mnt
    mount -o bind /dev  dev
    mount -o bind /sys  sys
    mount -o bind /proc proc
    chroot /mnt
    update-grub
    exit
   ```
4. Update `/mnt/etc/fstab` adding there `subvol=@` as an option.
5. Reboot. You will boot to the subvolume. Make sure that it is the case by

   ```
    mount | grep vda2
   ```

It should show something like

```
   /dev/vda2 on / type btrfs (rw,relatime,space_cache,subvolid=257,subvol=/@)
```

6. Now you can mount the top subvolume somewhere and delete its contents except `/@`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed steps. It worked without any issues on a Vultr VPS.

Comment: BTRFS is great. It should receive a lot more appreciation than it does. I use it everywhere. I have not used Ubuntu in a long time, but coming back to Ubuntu I had to make sure I had BTRFS set up the way I like it. Can't be without it. :-)

Comment: Looks like you need to remove `mount -o bind /boot boot` step again. When mounted, it created inappropriate symlnks and after I removed the original root fs, the VPS booted into grub rescue.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. `grub` placed data to the original `/boot` instead of the `/@/boot`

Comment: The error looks like: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70538/grub-error-file-grub-i386-pc-normal-mod-not-found

Comment: If it was a real hardware that would be quite easy to fix. Boot with a Live system, chroot to `@` again and update grub another time. But I am not sure how to do it with VPS.

Comment: If you can reach the fs, then just copy with `cp -a`. But it may be removed now.

Comment: I am not a grub expert either, sry. The `/boot` was a mistake.

Comment: I have this working now. In your step 3 (after chroot), my first step was to update `/etc/fstab`. Then I had add `update-initramfs -u` and I had to use `grub-install /dev/vda; grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` instead of `update-grub`. I'm not sure if everyone will need these steps. My setup is a little more complex than the example. The problem I kept running into was that it would not boot into my new subvolume. Error was "new mount options do not match the existing superblock, will be ignored." These steps resolved that. If you have further suggestions, let me know. Thank you!

Comment: in step 4. it shoud read: `/mnt/etc/fstab` because you already mounted the subvolume @ to /mnt. Inside /mnt there cannot be the folder `@`. `@` is in `/`

Comment: And I needed the procedure @MountainX described (Ubuntu Server 20.04)

Comment: @JürgenHörmann You are correct.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution which works on Ubuntu Server 20.04. It creates `@` subvolume before the first boot and removes all files from `/` volume.

1. Do the installation of Ubuntu 20.04 with BTRFS root partition, but don't reboot after the system installation.
2. Switch to terminal (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>).
3. Switch to root user and umount all devices other than the BTRFS partition:

   ```
   sudo -i
   umount /target/boot/efi
   umount -l /target/run
   umount /target/cdrom
   ```

   If you have other mount points (i.e. `/home`) umount them too.
4. Create `@` subvolume and move all files into it:

   ```
   cd /target
   btrfs subvolume create @
   ls | grep -v @ | xargs mv -t @
   ```
5. umount your BTRFS partition and mount it again pointing this time to the `@` subvolume. It is also a good time to define some extra mounting options (in my example there are some recommended options for SSD devices). I assume BTRFS volume is under `/dev/sda2` (adjust accrdingly)

   ```
   cd /
   umount /target
   mount -o subvol=@,ssd,noatime,space_cache,commit=120,compress=zstd:2 /dev/sda2 /target
   ```
6. Now it's time to complete the system by mounting all necessary devices and then switch to it with `chroot` (I assume your boot partition is `/dev/sda1`)

   ```
   mount /dev/sda1 /target/boot/efi
   mount --bind /proc /target/proc
   mount --bind /dev /target/dev
   mount --bind /sys /target/sys
   chroot /target
   ```

   If you've created some other partitions (i.e. `/home`) mount them here too
7. Open `fstab` in editor:

   ```
   vi /etc/fstab
   ```

   and update the line with BTRFS partition, i.e.:

   ```
   UUID=xxx / btrfs default,subvol=@,ssd,noatime,space_cache,commit=120,compress=zstd:2  0 0
   ```
8. Finally, setup the bootloader (I assume `/dev/sda`)

   ```
   update-initramfs -u -k all
   grub-install --recheck /dev/sda
   update-grub 
   exit
   ```
9. Get back to your installer (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) and reboot. Ubuntu should boot to your `@` subvolume.

Comment: Thank you. Those steps look good. I will try them on my next install. If they work better than the other answer, I'll accept your answer instead.

Comment: Shouldn't Step 5 re-mount the subvolume at `/target` instead of `/mnt`? (i.e. `mount -o subvol=@,ssd,noatime,space_cache,commit=120,compress=zstd:2 /dev/sda2 /target`)